# Joi validation - allow field to be optional but when supplied must be a positive integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, joi

I have a field in a JOI schema that I would like to be optional (i.e. undefined is accepted, and null is also accepted), however if a value for it is supplied, it must be a positive integer.  How might I go about achieving this?

Here is what I have tried so far, with the field to validate being "capacity" however it does not seem to work, it appears the ".when" statement is just being ignored:

```
const divebarSchema = joi.object({
  divebar: joi
    .object({
      title: joi.string().required(),
      capacity: joi.optional().allow(null),
      description: joi.string().required(),
      location: joi.string().required(),
      image: joi.string().optional().allow(""),
      map: joi.string().optional().allow(""),
    })
    .required()
    .when(joi.object({ capacity: joi.exist() }), {
      then: joi.object({ capacity: joi.number().integer().min(0) }),
    }),
});
```

Before the above I originally had no .when and instead the capacity rule was:

```
  capacity: joi.number().optional().allow(null).integer().min(0),
```

However that also did not work, it kept throwing the error "must be a number" when submitting a null value.

Comment: Have you tried removing the when completely, and just have `capacity: joi.integer().min(0)` in the original object?

Comment: @khenriksson thank for your comment.

`capacity: joi.integer().min(0)` doesn't work as I believe .integer only works on joi.number.  However capacity: `joi.number().integer().min(0)` isn't what I am looking for as that would not allow a null value.

I already tried adding the `allow(null)` rule with no luck - I updated my question description to explain what I tried beforehand.

Comment: try removing .required() after the joi.object()

Comment: @Sudhir thanks for your comment, but I'm afraid that did not change anything, it still seems like the `.while` is being ignored.  Also, removing `.required` is not what I want to do as I would like the overall object to be mandatory in the incoming request.

Answer (score 3):

According to Joi documentation [`optional`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2#anyoptional) does not include null you need to use `allow`

```
capacity: Joi.number().optional().integer().min(0).allow(null)
```

Comment: thanks for your post.  Do you mean take out the `.when` completely, and change my capacity rule to `capacity: joi.number().optional().integer().min(0).allow(null)` ?  This is essentially what I tried in the first place, the only difference is my `.allow()` was after `.optional()`.  I tried re-ordering it to what you have suggested but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: Correct. I tried out the rule in the joi sandbox and it worked for the scenarios {}, {capacity: null} & {capacity:3}. In fact optional seems redundant and works even when it is removed

Comment: Hmm that's strange.  In my app when I try what you said I still get the "must be a number" error for capacity: null

Comment: @Yob are you sure your `null` is not string? Did you try add `.allow(null, "null")`?

Comment: @soltex thanks for your comment.  I tried that and unfortunately that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`any.empty`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anyemptyschema) rather than `any.allow` to make it so that `null` ends up considered as an empty value. This will mean that `null` gets stripped out of the resulting value. If you don't want `null` capacity to be stripped from the resulting object, you can use `allow(null)` as mentioned in the other answer.

I've included a snippet of code that uses both for comparison and shows the validation rules fully applying for both.

```js
const divebarSchemaEmpty = joi.object({
  divebar: joi
    .object({
      title: joi.string().required(),
      capacity: joi.number().empty(null).integer().min(0),
      description: joi.string().required(),
      location: joi.string().required(),
      image: joi.string().allow(""),
      map: joi.string().allow(""),
    })
    .required(),
});

const divebarSchemaAllow = joi.object({
  divebar: joi
    .object({
      title: joi.string().required(),
      capacity: joi.number().allow(null).integer().min(0),
      description: joi.string().required(),
      location: joi.string().required(),
      image: joi.string().allow(""),
      map: joi.string().allow(""),
    })
    .required(),
});

const baseObject = {
  divebar: {
    title: 'capacity',
    description: 'test',
    location: 'here',
  }
};
const schemaRuns = [{
  title: 'Empty',
  schema: divebarSchemaEmpty
}, {
  title: 'Allow',
  schema: divebarSchemaAllow
}];
const runs = [{
    title: 'null capacity',
    data: {
      capacity: null
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'missing capacity',
    data: {}
  },
  {
    title: 'undefined capacity',
    data: {
      capacity: undefined
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'positive capacity',
    data: {
      capacity: 5
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'negative capacity',
    data: {
      capacity: -1
    },
    fails: true
  },
  {
    title: 'float capacity',
    data: {
      capacity: 0.25
    },
    fails: true
  }
];

for (const {
    title: baseTitle,
    data: override,
    fails
  } of runs) {
  for (const {
      title: schemaTitle,
      schema
    } of schemaRuns) {
    const title = `${schemaTitle}->${baseTitle}`;
    const data = { ...baseObject,
      divebar: { ...baseObject.divebar,
        ...override,
        title
      }
    };
    try {
      const result = joi.attempt(data, schema);
      if (fails) {
        throw new Error(`${title} succeeded validation when expected to fail`)
      }
      console.log(`${title} passed with data`, result);
    } catch (err) {
      if (joi.isError(err)) {
        if (fails) {
          console.log(`${title} passed with error object`, err)
        } else {
          // unexpected error!
          console.error(err);
        }
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/joi@17.7.0/dist/joi-browser.min.js"></script>
```